# Jquery Dialog modal issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm stuck with this jquery dialog box.  I've searched reviewed my code and its just not sticking out to me what is wrong here.  I have a button that when clicked will display a list of coaches names.  What I'd like is when the user clicks on a name for the dialog box to open and display some data basically just another hidden div that I have.  But my issue is when the name is clicked the dialog box does appear but the modal isnt working and there is no styling to it just basically opens the box on top of the other boxes.

I'm using the google hosted libraries
Heres the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="coaches">
    <h3>Head Coaches </h3> 
    <br />
    <p class="coach">Example Coach Text</p>
</div>

<br />

<div class="displayInfo">
    Example Text
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(".coaches").click(function () {

    $(".displayInfo").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 450,
        title: "Example Text",
        modal: true,
        // overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000000", opacity: 0.5 }
    });

    $(".displayInfo").dialog('open');

});
```

Comment: Remove the `,` after `modal: true`

Comment: Did you forget the CSS file that comes with jQuery UI?

Comment: Your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/4kDLm/show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're saying it does appear, I'm suspecting you forgot to include the CSS file that comes with jQuery UI. Please make sure that you included the CSS File. As for the Javascript Issue, please remove that last `,` - it will cause havoc in Internet Explorer

Comment: Wow I feel like a real jacka.... for this one thanks had my other css files included but not that one...

Comment: @TroyBryant No problem. if I have solved your problem can you please mark my answer as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code you've written here

```
    $(".displayInfo").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 450,
        title: "Example Text",
        modal: true,
       // overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000000", opacity: 0.5 }
    });
```

Did you forget to remove the `,` after `model: true` ? That's not valid syntax in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing went wrong in loading CSS.

You have to include **[jquery-ui.css](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

in your document `<head>`

**[SEE FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d2ErJ/)**